# How to implement takeTurn with a rotating playOrder?

Tags: java

How could this takeTurn method be nested with a playOrder to achieve the following player/turn combinations?

```
{
 ...
 for(int i=0;i<NUM_PLAYERS;i++)
{
players[i].takeTurn();
```

}
   ....

```
    playOrder
```

2Players
turn1    Player1 Player2 Player1 player2
turn2   Player2 Player1 Player2 Player1

3Players
turn1   Player1 Player2 Player3 player1
turn2   Player2 Player3 Player1 player2 
turn3   Player3 Player1 Player2 player3

4Players
turn1   Player1 Player2 Player3 player4
turn2   Player2 Player3 Player4 player1 
turn3   Player3 Player4 Player1 player2
turn4   Player4 Player1 Player2 player3

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<NUM_PLAYERS;i++) {
  for(int playOrder = 0; playOrder < 4; playOrder++) {
    players[(i + playOrder) % NUM_PLAYERS].takeTurn();
  }
}
```

.. or perhaps

```
for(int i=0;i<NUM_PLAYERS;i++) {
  players[(i + turnNumber) % NUM_PLAYERS].takeTurn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take a dequeue in C++ which is a queue where you can push and pop from both the ends,

```
dequeue<int> turns;
```

then push your sequence for four players

```
for( int i=0; i<4; ++i )
  turns.push_back( i%NUM_PLAYERS + 1 );

while( take_turns() )
{
     print("Turn\n");
     print_dequeue();
     turns.push_back(turns.front());
     turns.pop_front();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be really slick you can use a Java list(ArrayList works) to do this really easily

(Assuming your class is called Player, and you have everything saved in a list called players)

```
while(continueTurns()) {

   for(Player p : players) {
      p.takeTurn();
   }

   players.add(players.remove(0));

}
```